# Import function from another folder python

Tags: python

Below is my file directory

```
.
├── README.md
├── func
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── abc.py
    └── def.py
```

abc.py

```
def test():
    return 'berjaya'
```

main.py

```
from ..utils import test
```

when I run python main.py

get an error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

how to solve the issue?

In `main.py` i have tried a few ways

1. from .utils import test
2. from ..utils import test

All got the same error

Comment: @SameerWaseem No, that's completely wrong, and a syntax error.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that Python does not give you access to the file system. You can hack your way around that, but the proper solution is to create a package and install it.